# Bigcommerce Authentication with Email Passwod

Tags: bigcommerce

We just launched a new Bigcommerce website API and I have a requirement to create an app for the same website. I wanted to begin with the authentication but I can't seem to find an API for logging in with username and password.

Is there a way I can call an API and pass username/email and a password and receive something like a token? If no, what is the best practice to make an app for Bigcommerce websites.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to get authentication.

1. Building a script that will not be used in the Control Panel or running a quick query in Postman. 
   You will need to get an API Key and Token from the Control Panel. This can only be created by the store owner: https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Store-API-Accounts/
2. Creating an app for a single store or several stores: You will need a client id and a client secret. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#app-registration
3. There is also the Customer Login API https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/storefront.html#storefront-api-apps. This is allows for single sign on so customers can programmatically be logged into their account on the BigCommerce Storefront.